# Convert double to scientific notation with specific number after decimal points

Tags: c#, double, scientific-notation

I want to convert double to scientific notation like this:

```
-0.00752382528 => -.752383E-1
```

can i do this with .ToString()  or Regex?

Comment: `-.752383E-1` is not proper scientific notation - even if it were, it does not match your original value.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @DStanley, you'r right, but it's a conversion that is executed in an old software and i should rewrite it.

Answer (score 21):

You can either use the [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for scientific notation:

```
(-0.00752382528).ToString("E5")   // returns "-7.52383E-003"
```

or if you don't want the leading zeros in the exponent, use a [custom string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierExponent):

```
(-0.00752382528).ToString("0.00000E0")   // returns "-7.52383E-3"
```

Comment: I know these string formatting but i have to convert as described in answer. i think i have to write a custom method to do that.

Comment: In your example using ToString("E5") which gives :
-7,52383E-003
It will not be -.752383E-1 ? Seems like you are a factor of x10 off. -0.007.. vs -0.07 vs

ToString("E") gives you the scientific notation and the number of decimals in "E5" is five decimals. No need for regex.