# convert to double 5.55111512312578E-17

Tags: c#

How to convert `-5.55111512312578E-17` to `5.55`?

my code:

```
var value=reader11["PendingQty"].ToString().Replace('-', ' ');
var a=String.Format("{0:0.00}", value);
```

i also Tried : value= Math.round

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert double to scientific notation with specific number after decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851179/convert-double-to-scientific-notation-with-specific-number-after-decimal-points)

Comment: @Tachyon he wants the other way around

Comment: How is `-5.55.....E-17` equivalent to `5.55`? Is there an overflow from MinValue back to MaxValue?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, no It's  `.Replace('-', ' ')`. It's not a double it's a string

Comment: Instead of removing things from the string what about using the approiate math function to get the absolute value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Then we have an other issue.. 5.55111512312578E-17 -> 5.55 but what for E-18, E-15 ? Do you only what the 3 first significatif number?

Comment: `var a = value.Substring(0, 4);` will give you your expected result.

Comment: @xdtTransform I'm asking from the mathematics perspective - these two values are obviously different - the first, being written in a regular decimal notation would be `-0.0000000000000000555111512312578` - That's clearly not `5.55`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, From a math perspective, I'm not sure mantissa and exponent mean anything to op. There should be bitwise operation to remove the exponent part from the double. With this complexity Op is better of viewing it as a string. It's not math it's not pretty but as the question stand it's hard to get more out of it.

Comment: Getting the  fractional coefficient from a double looked like a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-5.55111512312578E-17 is equal to 0.0000000000000000555111512312578. You could get this value by doing this:

```
double output = Double.Parse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(output.ToString("F99").TrimEnd('0'));
```

But as far as I understood, you actually only want to first three digits, so I would do a string manipulation:

```
input.Substring(1,4);
```

This takes 4 characters, starting at the second position. If you have positive values too, simply check and read from the first digit on:

```
var res = "";
if (input.StartsWith("-")) {
    res = input.Substring(1,4));
} 
else {
    res = input.Substring(0,4);
}
```

Comment: To ensure the number gets parsed correctly you can use `double.Parse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Yes that's right, I left that out because I don't think that's whats wanted, but you are right, we should do that. I edited my answer to make it more complete / correct.