# Format decimal String to scientific notation in a specific format

Tags: c#, format

I want to format a string (e.g "000.14") to scientific notation in a specific layout => 1.5E-3

The code i've written so far looks like this:

```
foreach (TextBox obj in tbList)
                    if (obj.Enabled == true)
                    {
                        sWriteLines.Add("\t\t\t" + (String.Format((double.Parse(obj.Text) * 1e-9).ToString(), "E-")).Replace(",", "."));
                    }
```

The output is written into a "ini"/xml file which looks like this:

```
<default>
        <current>
            1E-8
            15E-9
            5E-8
            15E-8
            5E-7
            15E-7
            5E-6
            15E-6
            50E-6
            15E-5
        </current>
        <interval>
            200
            1000
            200
        </interval>
    </default>
```

The problem is the result I get from the code above looks like this: 1.5E-05
How is it possible to force the Format methode to format the string like this: 15E-6 (no '.' and no '0' between E/- and the rest of the exponent?
Or is there an alternative and better way to do so?

Thanks and greetings
Emjack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert double to scientific notation with specific number after decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851179/convert-double-to-scientific-notation-with-specific-number-after-decimal-points)